# how to fetch the id or class of a textbox if not known

Tags: jquery

i am using a jquery functionality which uses the dasher java applet(a writing aid)
using which when one clicks on an input area(mostly textboxes) the popup window opens and the dasher starts working
this jquery element works on any web page this means i should not know the id or the class of each and every text area but then how o fetch its id(i mean how to access it)

this is the code for the jquery plugin i am using
hope this is of some help

```
var dasherApplet = $('<applet />'); 

    dasherApplet.attr({
        'height':'100%',
        'width':'100%',
        'archive':farfalla_path+'plugins/dasher/Dasher.jar',
        'code':'dasher/applet/JDasherApplet.class'
    });

var dasherDiv = $('<div id="farfalla_dasher"></div>');

    dasherDiv.css({
        'position':'absolute',
        'top':0,
        'left':0,
        'width':'100%'
    });

    dasherApplet.appendTo(dasherDiv);
    dasherDiv.appendTo('body').hide();

jQuery.fn.dasher = function(){

    dasherDiv.toggle();

};  


$('textarea, input').click(function() {
    $(this).dasher();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
$('textarea, input').click(function() {
    $(this).dasher();
    alert(this.id);
});
```

Comment: Or even just `this.id`. Not everything needs to be wrapped in jQuery :)

Comment: @Phil - You're right, of course.  I just had dollar-signs in my eyes ;-)  I've fixed the answer.

Comment: hey thanx this worked what i am trying to do here is that this java applet has a textbox in which some text is written when the user perform a certain action on the java applet. as you must have guessed till now i want to fetch the text written on that "java's textbox" and use it in the jquery script so that it can be populated on the html textbox I hope you understood this. Have I made myself clear?

Comment: Ah.  You'd probably have to check the documentation for the Java applet to see if that's possible.  The text-box wouldn't be accessible by jQuery directly as it's not part of the DOM.

Comment: the only thing I know about the applet is that the name of the textbox in that applet is "EditBox" and the function returning its text is

public String getCurrentEditBoxText() {

  return EditBox.getText();

 }

Answer (score 0):

```
  $('textarea, input').click(function() {
       var id =  this.id;

    });
```

Comment: hey thanx
this worked
what i am trying to do here is that this java applet has a textbox in which some text is written when the user perform a certain action on the java applet. as you must have guessed till now i want to fetch the text written on that "java's textbox" and use it in the jquery script so that it can be populated on the html textbox
I hope you understood this. Have I made myself clear?

Comment: the problem is that once this java thing starts working i cannot bring the focus back to my current page
i cannot append a button on to the java element as i am unable to change the source code and each action through teh keyboard button is defined in the textbox of the java applet
for instance I tried this



$(function() {
var keycode=e.keycode;
if(keycode==27) {
divDasher.hide(); 
}
});