# accessing java applet in jquery

Tags: jquery

i am having a java applet within a jquery functionality rather a plugin where the applet is initiated whenever the plugin script is executed .
the applet has a textbox wherein some text is written due to some action as performed by the user what I want is to fetch the text written in that textbox(whose Id is unknown even the the name or the id of the applet).
any help is highly appreciated

```
var dasherApplet = $('<applet />'); 

    dasherApplet.attr({
        'height':'100%',
        'width':'100%',
        'archive':farfalla_path+'plugins/dasher/Dasher.jar',
        'code':'dasher/applet/JDasherApplet.class'
    });

var dasherDiv = $('<div id="farfalla_dasher"></div>');

    dasherDiv.css({
        'position':'absolute',
        'top':0,
        'left':0,
        'width':'50%'
    });

    dasherApplet.appendTo(dasherDiv);
    dasherDiv.appendTo('body').hide();

jQuery.fn.dasher = function(){

    dasherDiv.toggle();
 };
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to fetch the id or class of a textbox if not known](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183615/how-to-fetch-the-id-or-class-of-a-textbox-if-not-known)

Answer (score -1):

I have never seen any mechanism that allows a JavaScript script to introspect into a Java applet. I hope no such mechanism exists.

Don't let the word 'Java' in 'JavaScript' fool you -- the two have *nothing in common*.